# Way to turn on WAN antenna (mobile broadband) while leaving LAN antenna (wifi) off?

Tags: wireless

My laptop has integrated Mobile Broadband so it can get internet from cell phone waves when I'm away from home. It also has WiFi so it can get internet by connecting to my wireless router when I'm at home.

I have a Lenovo laptop and when I first got it it had Windows installed. Using Windows I was able to selectively turn on/off the "WiFi" antenna and/or the "Mobile Broadband" antenna. I could have both on, both off, or one on and one off.

Using my laptop's Fn keyboard shortcut to activate the antennas in Ubuntu appears to be an all on or all off action. Battery life when using Ubuntu is not the greatest. So I was thinking it might be helpful to make sure that unnecessary antennas are not on when they don't need to be. So when I am away from home and using Mobile Broadband is there a way I can disable the WiFi antenna, and vice versa for when I am at home?

Answer (score 1):

yes!  I just discovered this recently myself - `rfkill` lets you manage switching all your various radio devices

`rfkill list`

to show devices, and their on/off (aka "block/unblock") status

`rfkill unblock wwan`

should switch on your built in 3g.  `man rfill` for more info!